# jquery animate function on clicking the single button

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
    $('.edit').click(function () {
    var anim = 0;
    if(anim == 0){
        $('.foo_menu1').animate({
            bottom:"0px",
            opacity: "1",
            }, 600);

        $('.foo_menu2').animate({
            bottom:"-47px",
            opacity: "0",
            }, 600);

        anim += 1;
    }else{
        $('.foo_menu1').animate({
            bottom:"-47px",
            opacity: "0",
            }, 600);

        $('.foo_menu2').animate({
            bottom:"0px",
            opacity: "1",
            }, 600);
            anim=0;
    }
    });
})
```

I'm Novice to jQuery. please help me
I have One button and two div boxes. by default the first div box(foo_menu1) will appear.
while click on the button the the first box will appear and second one should disappear.

but when I click the first time its working good upto the first IF condition.
but if I click again the same btn, It doesnt go to inside of the else function.

Comment: Move `var anim = 0;` outside the click function.  You're resetting anim to zero every click.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `var anim = 0;` outside and make it a global variable.

```
var anim = 0;

$('.edit').click(function () {
  if(anim == 0){
  // code
  } else {
  }
})
```

Otherwise you're reinitializing it on click.

Also, I suggest you look at the `.data()` API of jquery if you want to store data pertaining to the elements. This will avoid global variables in your scope.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/